# Disable Responsive Layout with Pavo Home Page Builder in Open Cart

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

Hi, i need to disable "Extra Small Devices" layout in my Pavo theme in Open Cart CMS. thank you for your help.

Comment: Adnan, Opencart is a eCommerce, not a CMS and if you want to disable responsive layout then remove responsive css part on your theme.

Comment: Thank you for your tips.  Yes currently I'm deep dive into css to disable responsive css